# How can i import to opencart database from existing database

Tags: mysql, database, opencart

i have existing database. I want to import datas from my database to opencart. Table's names and row's name not same. For example i want to add customers to opencart. Can i do this programmatically? Is it possible to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write script to apply ETL.

ETL stands for Extract, Transform and Load

Extract from your current database In which you have data right now.

Transform into open cart database

Load into the open cart database